# React api calling and create same div by 'map' method

Tags: reactjs, api

I want to call api and generate div using data from api, but I don't know why this code is not working. It doesn't show anything on the page.

This is my code. `countryArray` is an object array, and it has property of `population`, `name`, `continent`, `capital`.

```
import React from 'react'

function Countries() {
    fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((countryArray)=>{
      return (
        <div>
        {countryArray.map((country)=>(
            <div className="Country_wrapper">
            <div className="Flag_wrapper">
                
            </div>
            <div className="Explanation_wrapper">
                <h2>{country.name}</h2>
                <p>Population: {country.population}</p>
                <p>Region: {country.continents}</p>
                <p>Capital: {country.capital}</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
        ))}
        </div>
      )
    },
    (err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
 

  
}


export default Countries
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a jsx element. The usual way of doing data fetching inside react component is to do it inside an effect.
A minimal example would be like this.

```
function Countries() {
    const [countryArray, setCountryArray] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async function () {
            const res = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
            const json = await res.json();
            setCountryArray(json)
        })()

    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {countryArray.map((country)=>(
                <div className="Country_wrapper">
                    <div className="Flag_wrapper">

                    </div>
                    <div className="Explanation_wrapper">
                        <h2>{country.name.common}</h2>
                        <p>Population: {country.population}</p>
                        <p>Region: {country.continents}</p>
                        <p>Capital: {country.capital}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Ofc you should also take care of race conditions, errors, loading states, or use a library that does all this stuff for you and more like react query.

Check the documentation for more information, [fetching data](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#fetching-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can't return jsx from `fetch`, that won't be rendered.

Use `useState` inside a `useEffect` to save the data, then return from the functinon itself

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Countries() {

    const [ data, setData ] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
      function getData() {
        fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((countryArray) => setData(countryArray)
        );
      };
      getData();
    }, [ ]);

    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((country)=>(
                <div className="Country_wrapper">
                    <div className="Flag_wrapper">

                    </div>
                    <div className="Explanation_wrapper">
                        <h2>{country.name.common}</h2>
                        <p>Population: {country.population}</p>
                        <p>Region: {country.continents}</p>
                        <p>Capital: {country.capital}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

          
ReactDOM.render(<Countries />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Demo takes quite some time to load, so here's a pic:

[image]

Comment: Doing so, fetch function will be run every times the component renders, imagine there is a controlled input in the component, it will trigger the fetch on each key stroke

Comment: you're completely right, thanks for pointing that out. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I totally didn't know that I had to use useEffect() when fetching the api. Also I realized I also had error 'Object is not a valid child' bc I wrote {country.name}, not {country.name.common}... Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there first of all you need save the api data in a state and then fetch the api in useEffect then you can use the api data in your react app

```html
import React , {useState , useEffect}  from 'react';


function app() {
const [examples , setExamples] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
 fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
 .then((res) => res.json())
 .then((data) => {
 setExamples(data);
 
 })
 .catch((err) => console.log(err));
},[]);

return(
<>
<div>
  {
examples.map((example) => (
  <div className="Country_wrapper">
        <div className="Flag_wrapper">
            
        </div>
        <div className="Explanation_wrapper">
            <h2>{example.name.official}</h2>
            <p>Population: {example.population}</p>
            <p>Region: {example.continents}</p>
            <p>Capital: {example.capital}</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
))
  }

</div>
</>

);
      
}

export default app
```

this code is working

Comment: Thank you! I totally didn't know that I had to use useEffect() when fetching the api. It helped a lot.